# Let users download only the images that fits their devise resolution & naming convention

Tags: ios, resolution

I have an app with thousands  of images.
Except of the UI that comes with the binary all the other images are downloaded from a server after an In App Perches transaction.

I wish to make 4 different packs of images for each resolution and let the users download only the graphics that they need.

1. In this case should I use @2x or just the name of the image?
2. Is there any problem you can think of with this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case should I use @2x or just the name of the image?

Either approaches will work in the scenario you described. Specifying the `@2x` suffix in your code will work as well as referring the image by its base name and letting the framework add the suffix.

> Is there any problem you can think of with this approach?

I cannot see any, but I would prefer the approach of not specifying the suffix explicitly. The code will be cleaner.